# How to make a simple shell script that checks if the system has a process with the name specified?

Tags: bash, shell, operating-system

Pretty much a script that checks if the system has a process with the name specified. If it does find any of the processes, it kills all of them, reporting how many processes have been terminated, otherwise it echoes that no such process exists.

for example:
 $ terminateProcess [a running cpp program]
should kill all the [given file name] processes.

Can any body get me started..

Comment: You should check whether such a program already exists before starting to write your own.  Then you'd find `pkill` and save yourself some effort.

Answer (score 0):

No need to make a shellscript, pkill exists for years. man pkill:

```
 pkill  will  send  the  specified  signal  (by default SIGTERM) to each
       process instead of listing them on stdout.

       -c, --count
              Suppress  normal  output; instead print a count of matching pro‐
              cesses.  When count does not match anything, e.g. returns  zero,
              the command will return non-zero value.

       Example 2: Make syslog reread its configuration file:
              $ pkill -HUP syslogd
```